# How to watch other console without notification?

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen, tty

I want to see what is freelance admin doing to my server. But all solutions i have found - screen, conspy, vnc does't met my needs.

Conspy is great but i have to ask free-lancer to run it first to see what is happening. I want to connect into other tty and see whats happening without sending keys. Only viewing.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

How about hiring a freelancer you can trust? This kind of spying takes a lot of time/effort, and you're not even guaranteed to see when he's doing something bad.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, if not completely secure option, would be to set their shell to `exec script`, e.g. in ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, etc, set:

```
exec script /path/to/logs/script_$(id -nu)_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
```

Note I say this isn't secure, because they could delete or modify the log file. It would allow you to `tail` the log though.

Comment: script logs can't be tailed, you need to use scriptreplay :)

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. Although you don't have to use scriptreplay once the log is done (i.e. user has logged out). It works fine to read it with `less -r`.

Answer (score 0):

although Im agree with Dennis Kaarsemaker but you may like to use following tools:

https://github.com/a2o/snoopy
http://sniffy.sourceforge.net/

another solution without installing thrid party tools on your server will be using the "w" command which display which user execute what commands.